# DataGridView not avaiable on Visual Studio 2019 ToolBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to Visual Studio and in trying to follow a tutorial I can't seem to find the DataGridView on the ToolBox for Windows Forms. I understand I can go to "Choose Toolbox Items" to select what I want but even then when I try to drag and drop the DataGridView it doesn't allow me to drop it.

I don't understand it because in every tutorial I watch this seems to be a pretty straightforward operation. If this is not possible, or if this is not the control I should be using, what is the other option to display a datatable on windows forms?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the project is a `.NET Core` project and I believe that `.NET Core` is still a work in progress. However, I am pretty sure you can add the `DataGridView` through code. To get the grid in the tool box, create a new “.NET Framework” winform’s project.

Comment: In .NET Core3.0, DataGridView is not yet available. Please refer to [Windows Forms Designer for .NET Core Released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the fix:**

1. Trying adding `using System.Windows.Forms;`. From .Net Framework only.

**OR**

2. After watching your image I think that it is a fresh project. So, create a new project. ***(Windows Form App(.Net Framework)), don't use .Net Core (still in progress*** as @JhonG said).